# How to run a subset of a data frame through R function?

Tags: r, function, subset

I am trying to set up a function that runs a regression analysis on variables of choice (data.var1,data.var2) from a particular subset of my master data frame, but the function is operating over the entire data frame rather than just the subset that I want it to, no matter whether I define the subset within or outside of the function.

```
#Function subsetting data by temp and running regression
varReg21C <- function(data.var1,data.var2) {
  data21C <- subset(allPursuit,allPursuit$temp == 21)
  fitData <- lm(data.var1 ~ data.var2, data21C)
  regData <- summary(fitData)
  anovaData <- anova(fitData)
  reg21C <- list(fitData=fitData,regData=regData,anovaData=anovaData)
}

#OR

#Function running regression on data already in subset
data21C <- subset(allPursuit,allPursuit$temp == 21)
data21C
data25C <- subset(allPursuit,allPursuit$temp == 25)
data25C
data29C <- subset(allPursuit,allPursuit$temp == 29)
data29C

varReg21C <- function(data.var1,data.var2) {
  fitData <- lm(data.var1 ~ data.var2, data21C)
  regData <- summary(fitData)
  anovaData <- anova(fitData)
  reg21C <- list(fitData=fitData,regData=regData,anovaData=anovaData)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have `data.var1` and `data.var2` floating in your environment. You need to define all the inputs and prevent reading directly from the environment, so if we write it like:

```
varReg <- function(data.var1,data.var2,DataFrame,TempChoice) {
  data <- subset(DataFrame,temp == TempChoice)
  Form <- paste(data.var1,"~",data.var2)
  fitData <- lm(Form, data)
  regData <- summary(fitData)
  anovaData <- anova(fitData)
  return( list(fitData=fitData,regData=regData,anovaData=anovaData))
}

allPursuit = data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100),z=runif(100),
temp=sample(c(21,25,29),100,replace=TRUE))

varReg("x","y",allPursuit,21)[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Form, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
     0.3126       0.1494 

varReg("x","y",allPursuit,25)[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Form, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
    0.55069      0.01734
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I tried your function but ran into this error: 
`> varReg(lunge.time,lunge.dist,allPursuit,21)[[1]]
Error in paste(data.var1, "~", data.var2) : object 'lunge.time' not found`
Even though you can see in my data frame that 'lunge.time' is there: 
`$ lunge.time : int  84 84 92 76 84 100 68 80 120 85...`

Comment: it should be varReg("lunge.time","lunge.dist",allPursuit,21)[[1]], take note of the double  quotes ```"```

Comment: Ah okay, that fixed it. Thanks!